# vuejs category and keyword filter

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, categories, keyword

Hey guys I've been at this for a while Im trying to filter my templates by category and keywords using buttons. I have a vuejs app that uses the filter method. It works really well except when I have no keywords selected and have start selecting multiple categories. For example I have a template called test that is associated to both the category of sports and the category of holiday. When both are selected I get a duplicate. Im really close on this I've just been stuck on this part for about a week now. I realize this is alot of code but its clean, readable and wouldn't make sense unless I gave you an overview.

Heres a fiddle displaying the code
https://jsfiddle.net/rshba6jz/

Heres the front end code

```
<?php require_once('header.php');
require_once('database.php');

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category) categories, GROUP_CONCAT(k.keyword) keywords FROM dataclayTemplates t LEFT JOIN dataclayCategoryLink cl JOIN dataclayCategories c ON cl.categoryId=c.id ON t.id=cl.templateId LEFT JOIN dataclayKeywordLink kl JOIN dataclayKeywords k ON kl.keywordId=k.id ON t.id=kl.templateId GROUP BY t.id"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if($row["categories"] == null) {
      $row["categoryArray"] = [];
    } else {
      $row["categoryArray"] = array_unique(explode(",",$row["categories"]));
    }
    unset($row["categories"]);
    if($row["keywords"] == null) {
      $row["keywordArray"] = [];
    } else {
      $row["keywordArray"] = array_unique(explode(",",$row["keywords"]));
    }
    unset($row["keywords"]);
    $templateArray[] = $row;
  }
}

$result->close();

$categoryArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT category FROM dataclayCategories;"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($categoryArray, $row['category']);
  }
}

$result->close();

$keywordArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT keyword FROM dataclayKeywords;"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($keywordArray, $row['keyword']);
  }
}

$result->close();

$mysqli->close();


?>
<div v-cloak id="templates" class="container content">

    <div class="col-lg-3 visible-lg-block hidden-md" id="SearchTemplatesLargeContainer">
        <form role="form" role="form" onsubmit="return false">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="searchBar">Search</label>
                <input v-model="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search Tempates" id="searchBar" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Sort By</label>
                <select v-model="sortBy" class="form-control">
          <option value="renderTime">Render Time</option>
          <option value="az">A-Z</option>
          <option value="dateAdded">Newest</option>
        </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Categories</h5>
                <div v-for="category in categories" :class="category + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectCategory(category)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                    {{category}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Keywords</h5>
                <div v-for="keyword in keywords" :class="keyword + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectKeyword(keyword)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                    {{keyword}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--end lg template menu col-lg-3-->

    <!--search templates modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="searchTemplatesModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Search Templates</h2>
                    <!--end .modal-title-->
                </div>
                <!--end modal-header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Search</label>
                            <input v-model="searchQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search Tempates" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <!--.end searchQuery-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sort By</label>
                            <select v-model="sortBy" class="form-control">
                                <option value="renderTime">Render Time</option>
                                <option value="az">A-Z</option>
                                <option value="dateAdded">Newest</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <!--end sortBy-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h5>Categories</h5>
                            <div v-for="category in categories" :class="category + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectCategory(category)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                                {{category}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end categorys-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h5>Keywords</h5>
                            <div v-for="keyword in keywords" :class="keyword + 'Button'" v-on:click.prevent="selectKeyword(keyword)" class="btn btn-default categoryButton">
                                {{keyword}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end keywords-->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!--end .modal-body-->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">Search</button>
                </div>
                <!--end .modal-footer-->
            </div>
            <!--end .modal-content-->
        </div>
        <!--end .modal-dialog-->
    </div>
    <!-- end search templates modal-->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="mainHeading">Templates</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in searchResults" class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <video muted :src="mysource" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="mysouce" loop="loop"></video>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p>
                        <!--end card-title-->
                        <p v-show="displayCount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p>
                        <!--end user has no display card-text-->
                        <p v-show="displayCount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p>
                        <!--end user has display card text-->
                        <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                        <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                        <!--logged in and has display button-->
                        <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==false" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a>
                        <!--not logged in button-->
                        <a href="profile.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
                    </div>
                    <!--end card-body-->
                </div>
                <!--end card-->
            </div>
            <!-- end col-md-4-->
        </div>
        <!--end row-->
    </div>
    <!--end col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12-->
</div>
<!--end templates app-->
<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#templates',
  data: {
    loggedIn: false,
    displayCount:'<?php if(isset($_SESSION['displayCount'])){echo $_SESSION['displayCount'];} else{echo 0;}?>',
    searchQuery:'',
    templateArray: <?php echo json_encode($templateArray); ?>,
    filteredTemplateArray: <?php echo json_encode($templateArray); ?>,
    categories: <?php echo json_encode($categoryArray); ?>,
    selectedCategories: [],
    keywords: <?php echo json_encode($keywordArray); ?>,
    selectedKeywords: [],
    sortBy: ''
  },
  computed: {
      searchResults: function(){
          return this.filteredTemplateArray.filter((template)=>{
            return template.itemName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase());
          })
      }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.loggedIn=<?php if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])){echo $_SESSION['loggedIn'];} else {echo 0;}?>;
    this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
      return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
    });
  },
  watch: {
    sortBy: function() {
      if(this.sortBy == "az") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
        });
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
      this.sortBy="renderTime";
  },
  methods: {
    filter: function() {
      var filteredCategoryArray = [];
      var filteredKeywordArray = [];
      if(this.selectedCategories.length != 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.templateArray.length; i++) {
          for(var j = 0; j < this.selectedCategories.length; j++ ) {
            for(var k = 0; k < this.templateArray[i].categoryArray.length; k++ ) {
              if(this.templateArray[i].categoryArray[k] == this.selectedCategories[j]) {
                  console.log(this.templateArray[i].categoryArray[k]);
                  console.log(this.selectedCategories[j]);
                var arrayDuplicate = false;
                for(var l = 0; l < filteredKeywordArray.length; l++) {
                  if(filteredCategoryArray[l].id == this.templateArray[i].id) {
                    arrayDuplicate = true;
                  }
                }
                if(arrayDuplicate == false) {
                  filteredCategoryArray.push(this.templateArray[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.templateArray.length; i++){
          filteredCategoryArray.push(this.templateArray[i]);
        }
      }

      if(this.selectedKeywords.length != 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < filteredCategoryArray.length; i++) {
          for(var j = 0; j < this.selectedKeywords.length; j++ ) {
            for(var k = 0; k < filteredCategoryArray[i].keywordArray.length; k++ ) {
              if(filteredCategoryArray[i].keywordArray[k] == this.selectedKeywords[j]) {
                var arrayDuplicate = false;
                for(var l = 0; l < filteredKeywordArray.length; l++) {
                  if(filteredKeywordArray[l].id == filteredCategoryArray[i].id) {
                    arrayDuplicate = true;
                  }
                }
                if(arrayDuplicate == false) {
                  filteredKeywordArray.push(filteredCategoryArray[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < filteredCategoryArray.length; i++){
          filteredKeywordArray.push(filteredCategoryArray[i]);
        }
      }
      if(this.sortBy == "az") {
        filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
        filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
        filteredKeywordArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
        });
      }

      this.filteredTemplateArray = filteredKeywordArray;
      $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
    },
    selectCategory: function(category) {
      var categoryButton = $('.' + category + 'Button');
      categoryButton.toggleClass('categoryButtonSelected');
      if(this.selectedCategories.includes(category)){
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.selectedCategories.length; i++) {
          if(this.selectedCategories[i] != category) {
            array.push(this.selectedCategories[i]);
          }
        }
        this.selectedCategories = array;
      } else {
        this.selectedCategories.push(category);
      }
      this.filter();
    },
    selectKeyword: function(keyword) {
      var categoryButton = $('.' + keyword + 'Button');
      categoryButton.toggleClass('categoryButtonSelected');
      if(this.selectedKeywords.includes(keyword)){
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.selectedKeywords.length; i++) {
          if(this.selectedKeywords[i] != keyword) {
            array.push(this.selectedKeywords[i]);
          }
        }
        this.selectedKeywords = array;
      } else {
        this.selectedKeywords.push(keyword);
      }
      this.filter();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

I have the when a template gets clicked this is what is passed into my filteredTemplateArray in the vue inspector. If there are multiple items with the same id (in this case 223 I would like them to be filtered out so there are no duplicates. Its working fine with keywords but fails with categories. Im sure its simple but I really am stuck and some help would be great.

```
    filteredTemplateArray:Array[1]
0:Object
categoryArray:Array[3]
0:"Misc"
1:"Holiday"
2:"Sports"
dateAdded:"2018-10-01 17:54:22"
id:"233"
itemId:"fb41a01641bb2e769db412d3b21c2e3e"
itemName:"test"
keywordArray:Array[2]
0:"Snow"
1:"LensFlare"
projectPath:"M:/Projects/Generics/uploads/testLocation"
renderTime:"4"
stillImageLocation:"0.13"
tested:"0"
thumbName:"TEST"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a watcher that watches selectedCategories and when it changes run a method that filters out the duplicates and sets filtered categories back to the original array when the selectedCategories.length==0. This creates a category filter that counts up. for instance if sports and holidays are checked it will show only all items in sports and all items in holidays which seems to work better than counting down or showing the ones that only exist in both. I use app instead of this as its the variable i called my vue instance and because when you get deep into a function this does not always mean the app.

```
    watch: {
      selectedCategories(){
          this.categoryFilter();
      },
          sortBy(){
              this.sortTemplatesBy();
          }
    },
  methods: {
            sortTemplatesBy: function(){ 
      if(this.sortBy == "az") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
        });
      }
    },
      categoryFilter: function(){
          if(app.selectedCategories.length!=0){
          app.filteredTemplateArray=[];
          var templateArray = app.templateArray;
          for(i=0; i<app.selectedCategories.length; i++){
              var filtered=templateArray.filter(function(template){
                  var currentCategory=app.selectedCategories[i];
                  console.log("this is current category"+currentCategory+"end currentCategory");
                  var returnValue=template.categoryArray.includes(currentCategory);
                  console.log("this is i"+i+"end i");
                  console.log("this is return value"+returnValue+"end return value");
                  return returnValue;
              });
              console.log(filtered);
              app.filteredTemplateArray=app.filteredTemplateArray.concat(filtered);

      }
          var uniqueArray=[];
          var allResultsArray=app.filteredTemplateArray;
          for(j=0; j<allResultsArray.length; j++){
              if(uniqueArray.indexOf(allResultsArray[j]) == -1){
                  uniqueArray.push(allResultsArray[j])
              }
          }
          app.filteredTemplateArray=uniqueArray;
      } else {app.filteredTemplateArray=app.templateArray;}
          this.sortTemplatesBy();
      }
  }
```